# Derivative of $\sec^{-1} e^{2x}$, my answer differs from wolfram alpha.

Tags: calculus, wolfram-alpha

The problem: Find the derivative of $\sec^{-1} e^{2x}$ (\arcsec doesn't seem to work)

My work:

$u= e^{2x}$

$\mathrm{d}u = 2e^{2x}\,\mathrm{d}x$

The formula I know for the derivative of arcsec(u) is $\frac{u^{\prime}}{\vert u \vert \sqrt{u^2-1}}$

Which gives me:
$$\frac{2e^{2x}}{\vert e^{2x} \vert \sqrt{\left(e^{2x}\right)^2 -1 }}$$

simply!

$$\frac{2}{\sqrt{e^{4x}-1}} $$

always check your [work](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative%20arcsec%28e%5E%282x%29%29%20):

Wolframalpha gives: $$  \frac{2}{e^{2x}\sqrt{1-e^{-4x}}}$$

I have tried to several times to make sure they are algebraically the same, but atlas, I have failed on that attempt.   I know that wolfram alpha is more trustworthy than my mathematical skills.

THus, I wonder where my mistake lies.

Comment: Also not that you can type your answer and put $==$ then wolframalpha's answer and it will often tell you if they are equivalent or not. But doing the algebra yourself is still a good exercise!

Comment: I even prefer your (good) answer to WA's !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You haven't made a mistake.

$$e^{2x}\sqrt{1-e^{-4x}}=\sqrt{e^{4x}}\sqrt{1-e^{-4x}}=\sqrt{e^{4x}(1-e^{-4x})}=\sqrt{e^{4x}-1}$$